# How to set the immediate Association of the words returned from the request in ace editor?

Tags: ace-editor

How to set the immediate Association of the words returned from the request in ace editor?I want to associate the words back from the request immediately, but I tried all kinds of methods.

Comment: try adding some example code, now its hard to understand what do you mean by "immediate Association"

Comment: I want to manually control the appearance of the association word prompt box and the content of the association word prompt box@Johnny Willemsen

Comment: Now I have some associative words, I want to put it in the association word prompt box, and let the prompt box with the association word I just added it appear immediately.@Johnny Willemsen

Comment: by "associative  words" do you mean autocompletions?

Comment: I want to prompt manually

Comment: you need to update your question with code example and possibly screenshots, because currently it is impossible to understand what do you mean.

Comment: I now have a requirement to associate a table alias field in a SQL query, for example: "select * from table t where t. ", when the user enters "t.", the prepared field is associated.
The business scenario is: after the user inputs "t.", the prepared table field is displayed in the Lenovo prompt word box. That is, we spell the SQL in Navicat to associate the table field.

Comment: what are "Lenovo prompt" and "Navicat"? Seems like you have two questions here one about getting some data from ace, and the other is about displaying data in `Lenovo prompt word box` which is not related to ace or to web technologies in general. Try to edit this question to make the part related to ace more clear, and also show the code for some kinds of methods that you have already tried.